# Upload an excel file to AS400 using Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-midrange

We have an autodetach module in our email wherein the excel file attachments are detached to a specific folder in our network.

Is it possible that aside from detaching the file I could open the attachment and upload it into an AS400 file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use FTP to AS400 IFS from the network folder?
Then from AS400 IFS, use CPYFRMIMPF to PF?